# Threejs custom 3d geometry using vertices

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to make a quarter , only the long surface area not the sides, of a cylinder surface using vertices to make the custom geometry. I tried making a list of quads, but this code does not work. 
http://jsfiddle.net/R7pQB/32/

```
for(i = 90; i > 0; i -= 2 ){
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, quad1_y[i], quad1_z[i]) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( L, quad1_y[i], quad1_z[i]) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( L, quad1_y[i - 1], quad1_z[i - 1]) );
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 0, quad1_y[i - 1],quad1_z[i - 1]) );
    geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face4(0,1,2,3) );
}
```

Comment: is it a cylinder with no caps what you're trying to draw ?

Comment: yes, I'm just trying to draw a cylinder with no caps. Actually, I might want to draw half the cylinder at that... because, I want to scroll between two different textures

Answer (score 1):

As @newvalue points out, you are not incrementing the face indices.
You are pushing vertices to the mesh. next you need to connect them to a face.
I find it a lot easier to use a second counter which gets incremented by 4 for a Face4 instance. Also, instead of two loops, you could computer and add the vertices/faces in the same loop:

```
function initGeometry( R , L) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    var deg;
    var f = 0;  
    for( deg = 0; deg < 90; deg++,f += 4 ){
        var ca = deg * 0.01745329252;//cache current angle
        var na = (deg+1) * 0.01745329252;//cache next angle (could do with a conditional and storing previous angle)
        var ccos = Math.cos(ca);//current cos
        var csin = Math.sin(ca);//current sin
        var ncos = Math.cos(na);//next cos
        var nsin = Math.sin(na);//next sin

        var tl = new THREE.Vector3( R * ccos, L * .5, R * csin);//top left = current angle, positive y
        var bl = new THREE.Vector3( R * ccos,-L * .5, R * csin);//bottom left = current angle, negative y
        var tr = new THREE.Vector3( R * ncos, L * .5, R * nsin);//top right = next angle, positive y
        var br = new THREE.Vector3( R * ncos,-L * .5, R * nsin);//bottom right = next angle, negative y

        /*
        tl--tr
        |  /|
        | / |
        |/  |
        bl--br
        */
        geometry.vertices.push(tl,tr,br,bl);//notice vertices are added in (cw) order
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(f,f+1,f+2,f+3));//add the correct face indices, easy with a second counter

    }
```

some of the code is expanded so it's easier to understand the connection between vertices, their position in 3D space, as well as their position in the vertices array from where they are referenced when adding faces.

Based on your fiddle, here's the full listing:

```
var renderer;
var camera;
var scene;
var object;

initConfig();
initGeometry( 50, 300 );
startRender();

function initConfig() {
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 1, 100);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    scene.add(camera);
}

function initGeometry( R , L) {
    var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

    var deg;
    var f = 0;  
    for( deg = 0; deg < 90; deg++,f += 4 ){
        var ca = deg * 0.01745329252;//cache current angle
        var na = (deg+1) * 0.01745329252;//cache next angle (could do with a conditional and storing previous angle)
        var ccos = Math.cos(ca);//current cos
        var csin = Math.sin(ca);//current sin
        var ncos = Math.cos(na);//next cos
        var nsin = Math.sin(na);//next sin

        var tl = new THREE.Vector3( R * ccos, L * .5, R * csin);//top left = current angle, positive y
        var bl = new THREE.Vector3( R * ccos,-L * .5, R * csin);//bottom left = current angle, negative y
        var tr = new THREE.Vector3( R * ncos, L * .5, R * nsin);//top right = next angle, positive y
        var br = new THREE.Vector3( R * ncos,-L * .5, R * nsin);//bottom right = next angle, negative y

        /*
        tl--tr
        |  /|
        | / |
        |/  |
        bl--br
        */
        geometry.vertices.push(tl,tr,br,bl);//notice vertices are added in (cw) order
        geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face4(f,f+1,f+2,f+3));//add the correct face indices, easy with a second counter

    }

    object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x660033,         side:THREE.DoubleSide}));
    object.position.set(0,0,0);
    object.rotation.x = Math.PI * .35;//a bit of rotation to make the structure visible
    object.scale.set(.35,.35,.35);//again, to make things easier to see
    scene.add(object);
}

function startRender(){
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Also your mesh is pretty dense (90 faces for half a cylinder). 
You might want to try drawing your mesh using less segments, which will give you a chance to practice with vertices/faces indices.

Comment: Quick Question, why did you multiply the Length "L" by 0.5.. ?

Comment: @SleepyEngineer I've divided L by 2: half the size because when the vertices are offset by that size the pivot will be at the centre on that axis. this way your mesh will behave like most meshes in 3D :)

Comment: aaah I understand! I was trying to wrap my cylinder with a texture from imgur; though, it never came out right. I did soemthing similar to offsetting the cylinder to the center. http://jsfiddle.net/C5hfe/

Comment: Hi @GeorgeProfenza this answer seems deprecated using `Face4`.. can you update it?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Will do that when I get a chance. In the mean time, if should a matter of using two Face3 instances using the first 3, then the last 3 vertices that made a quad(Face4). (e.g. ```geometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(f,f+1,f+2));```). The only catch is to mind the winding(order of vertices) so the face normal pushes in the right direction. Hope these notes are useful until I can play with this again

Answer (score 0):

All the faces of your geometry have same vertex indices ?

```
 geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face4(0,1,2,3) );
```

Comment: I guess its better to ask, how does one make half a cylinder or a quarter in THREEjs

Comment: Your code is wrong because in each face of your geometry, indices is indices in geometry.vertices. So if you use this code, all the face has same vertex indices.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do the indices with the current threejs documentation, I just got most of this from scrambled examples. Is there a good example for threejs?

Comment: here is my fix code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JpU3L/9/). There is very good course here: [link](https://www.udacity.com/course/cs291) I learned a lot here.

Comment: I'm free now. So i hope that can help you. For example we have some vetices: [image](http://snag.gy/eKFzA.jpg). and here is some simple code: [code](http://pastebin.com/TTPRiQgv)

Comment: thank you for the help! I've register and been watching the udacity videos for 3D and THREEjS programming. :)